# spinnerAnimationBackgroundImage doesn't show svg

Tags: botframework, web-chat

I am trying to change the spinner image to an SVG file in my local system. Setting `spinnerAnimationBackgroundImage: './img/spinner-solid.svg'` shows empty space and only the text for making the connection. Setting spinnerAnimationHeight/spinnerAnimationWidth does affect the size of the empty space however.

I do not think it is an issue with reading files from my local filesystem because I am able to set the bot avatar image `botAvatarImage: './img/blank_avatar.svg'` with no problem.

I looked in the code further: https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/c5afaefa21e7bdf3082a7110040da52731314862/packages/component/src/Styles/StyleSet/SpinnerAnimation.js#L5

Does webchat expect gif type and svg is not supported?

Comment: I'm able to confirm the empty space when testing with other graphic file types. Does the same occur for you when trying .gif, .jpg, or .png? Incidentally, looking over the [test files](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/search?p=2&q=spinner&unscoped_q=spinner), they always send a .png file.

Comment: @StevenKanberg Yes I've tried with gif/jpg/png file types and the same white space occurs.